# Search Skype history using Windows search?

Tags: search, skype, windows-search

Is there some addon for Windows Search to search inside of Skype text chat history?

I have found [a solution for Google Desktop Search](https://extras.skype.com/1604/view), but none for the Windows search so far.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found so far is to export chat history to a text file on a regular basis so this file will be automatically indexed by WDS.
I created a small application base on Skype4COM to export chat. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Interesting. Simple, yet working. Did you consider hosting this on some open source hosting site, or making this publicly available in some way? I would definitely be interested to check it.

Comment: I'd also be interested in this as well if you wouldn't mind? We use Skype for communication across work sites and having regularly exportable logs of communications would be very useful.

Comment: I'd also be interested in taking a look at this, rather than reinventing it - any chance you can link it somewhere?